# Frustrating ACPI BIOS ERROR at boot. HP 15-G019WM UEFI laptop

Tags: boot, uefi, cmos

I have a HP 15 with UEFI & AMD processor from a client that just won't boot from any bootable media. "Your Pc ran into a problem and needs to restart Error: ACPI BIOS Error."

Prior to the error the laptop was last switched off by power button & starting it the following morning and when I did so, I got an ACPI BIOS Error - which prevents it from starting into Windows completely or loading any Windows Installation media! Now I have tried all possible CMOS jigs -loading BIOS defaults, secure boot off,enabling legacy mode,removing cmos RTC battery &e ven replacing the battery itself.

I even tried formatting the drive on another laptop using GPT partitioning meant for Windows 8.1 UEFI systems. Tried Windows 8,8.1 & Windows 10.Hard drive & RAM tests all pass as good.  The laptop detects bootable UEFI formatted flash drive but I get the same error soon after boot every single time. Booting in Legacy mode ends in the same error. Trying booting into safemode, recovery F8&F11, all end up at the same error.

UEFI is Insyde H20 vF.05. Am buffled having exausted all possible options. I need to know how to handle this ACPI BIOS Error whenever I try to boot a Windows partition.

Comment: I am confused. It will not boot at all but you are able to boot from UEFI formatted flash drive?

Comment: @Hennes Sorry posted in a hurry. I meant that the laptop detects bootable flash drive but encounters the same blue screen error as soon as I try to boot from it.  Edited the Qstn for Clarity

Answer (score 0):

Since I could install Ubuntu/Linux and run well on the same laptop I was later
able to solve this problem by trying different RAM sticks. The laptop was extremely choosy on which RAM would work without causing the ACPI BIOS error. Only then was I able to install  Windows and login to windows.

Comment: You should accept your answer if the issue is completely resolved.